# R & Shiny - Sidebar text alignment justified

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have created a Shiny application which you you can view right here:
http://www.agristats.eu/en/prices-agricultural-commodities/

The R code for this app is [here](https://github.com/iliastsergoulas/shinyapps/blob/master/prices/en/app.R).
The problem is with the text in the app's sidebar. It keeps hiding behind the plots, so I need its alignment to be justified within the sidebar. 
[image]
The respective code part is:

```
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(selectInput('commodity', 'Προϊόν', 
    choices = unique(data_quandl$data_product)),
    tags$footer(tags$p("This application is based on Quandl data."))))
```

What is more puzzling is that, within the same website, I have another similar application in which the respective sidebar text is correctly printed. You can view the app performing correctly [here](http://www.agristats.eu/en/subsidies/).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the `footer` outside `sidebarMenu` will do the trick as follows :

```
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
  selectInput('commodity', 'Προϊόν', choices = unique(data_quandl$data_product))
  ),
  tags$footer(
    tags$p("This application is based on Quandl data.")))
```

Output :

[image: snap1]

Other workaround is using `div` tag to align the text as well.

```
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
  selectInput('commodity', 'Προϊόν', choices = unique(data_quandl$data_product)),
  div(style="text-align:center","This application is based on",br(), "Quandl Data")
  ))
```

This results in :

[image: snap2]

Answer (score 1):

The one you are having the problem, footer is present inside the ul tag, issue is because of the `{white-space:nowrap}` rule on the ul.

If possible print the footer outside the ul tag, it should solve the problem.

or else try this property using custom css `{white-space:initial;}`

hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Your suggestion was pretty much the same with @ParthChaudhary but his/hers was more clear and well described so I accepted that one.